# SQL Select, Insert logic with IF Then Else cases

Tags: mysql

I am trying to migrate some old data into a new system. I have a table dump from the old system. To simplify things:

OldTable - Columns are Date, Flag, Payment, Payment2, Account

NewTable - Columns are Date, Flag, Payment, Account

I need to select the records from the old table, and if Flag = 1, Payment in the NewTable = Payment from OldTable, if Flag = 2, Payment in NewTable = Payment2 in OldTable.

There are several more if-then secenarios, but understanding how to solve this will solve all the other issues.

Comment: You're looking for CASE clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following query:

```
insert into newtable 
   ( Date, 
     Flag, 
     Payment, 
     Account )
   select 
         Date, 
         Flag, 
         case when Flag = 1 then Payment 
              WHEN Flag = 2 THEN Payment2 END CASE, 
         Account 
      from 
         OldTable;
```